# How to find which column contains a specific value in a each row of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

I have a table in which columns are dynamic, i.e. say a there are six columns C1, C2, C3, V1, V2, V3.

C1, C2, C3 contains a field and corresponding values are inserted in V1, V2, V3.

in one row field1 can be in the C2 column and the corresponding value will be in V2. for a particular ID (fixed column).
in the next row, field1 can be in the C1 column and the corresponding value will be in V1, for a different ID.

in this scenario how can we find which column contains field1 for a particular ID.

[image: Sample Table Structure]

Expected result is

[image]

Comment: UNPUVOT your data using UNION ALL with proper WHEREs, then query to single-paired (ID-C-V) table.

Comment: Please show us your expected results.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: @Strawberry It is a banking transaction table, where various fields don't come at the same time for a particular tnx right away. Some fields and values come a day or two days later once other authorities confirm it.

Comment: @VBoka edited for expected result

Comment: Is each value of Cx field unique over a record? i.e. is it possible that both C1 and C2 are Field1 in the same record?

Comment: in the same record, field1 can be in only one Cx Column. @Akina

Comment: @Anurodh Those facts make no difference to the essential point that this schema is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: 'various fields don't come at the same time ' does that mean you can have a c without a corresponding v ?

Comment: "I have a table in which columns are dynamic"  If so, you don't have a table in a SQL database.  Columns are well defined in a relational database.

Comment: @P.Salmon Not really, 
1. The fields which many times come from merchants can be totally new. Say a till now, some merchant was sending f1,f2,f3 fields for a particular transaction. From today t onwards they started to send F4, F6 instead.
2. So  in that transaction either a) that C is there so a corresponding v will be present can be null also(important thing is Merchant should mention there is a C). b) C is not there at all, so it will be null for both C and V.

Answer (score 1):

A normalised schema *might* look something like this...

```
id  x c v   
111 1 3 30 
222 1 1 10 
333 1 2 20 

111 2 1 10
222 2 2 20
333 2 3 30

111 3 2 20
222 3 3 30
333 3 1 10
```

...where a natural PK can be formed on (id,x)

Answer (score 0):

> in the same record, field1 can be in only one Cx Column

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN C1='Field1' THEN V1
                WHEN C2='Field1' THEN V2
                WHEN C3='Field1' THEN V3
                ELSE NULL
                END field1
FROM sourcetable
/* uncomment the next line 
   if 'Field1' value may be in none Cx column, 
   and you do not need in such records */
/* HAVING field1 IS NOT NULL */
```